# URL and Controller structure for parent-child-relationship

Tags: java, mvc, crud

I use an MVC web framework to create an application which contains a hierarchy:

```
Location <1-N> Devices <N-M> Services
```

I have a number of Locations. Each Locations can have several devices (represented by an 1-N relationship in the database). Each device runs services. The services (like http, ftp, etc) are defines in an extra table and are connected to the devices using an N-M relationship.

So far I have a model for each of the entities and one Location-controller for CRUD operations. Since the devices somehow belong to the location all the device CRUD-functions are located in the location controller as well. The services have their own controller. The url to access the data is structured like this:

```
/locations/    # to get an overview of the locations
/locations/*id*/    # to view the details of one location
/locations/*id*/edit    # to edit the details of one location
/locations/*id*/device/*deviceid*/    # to view details of a device
/locations/*id*/device/*deviceid*/edit    # to view details of a device
/services/     # list of all the services
/services/*id/    # view details of a service
```

Note: There are also urls to create and delete entries, which are omitted. But I think you get the idea.

Now to my questions: It feels wrong, and I think it is wrong to put all the functions inside the Location-controller, therefore I would like to move them so separate controllers. On the other hand, I like the URL-Structure, since it represents the hierarchy of the data pretty well. Furthermore I like when the URL structure corresponds with the Controllers.

What is the "better" solution: Separate controllers with combined URLs? Separate controllers, separate URLs? Or combined controller with combined URLs?

Comment: How do you track the history of installations of an individual device over time? Does the location have an affect on which services a device has or provides?

Comment: Devices have a fix location and cannot be moved between locations. The location has no influence on what services are running on the devices or on the services them self.

Answer (score 1):

Nested resources such as /locations/*id*/devices/*id* are typically placed in the same controller as the parent resource. For example, if you have a controller for locations, you would put the /locations endpoint in that controller as well as the /locations/*id*/devices endpoint. The nested devices controller would be placed in the same Controller class as the locations controller.

Here is an example using Spring Boot:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/locations")
public class LocationController {
    @GetMapping("/{locationId}/devices")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Device>> listDevicesForLocation(@PathVariable Long locationId, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Device> page = locationRepository.findById(locationId).findAll(
                PageRequest.of(
                        pageable.getPageNumber(),
                        pageable.getPageSize(),
                        pageable.getSortOr(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"))
                ));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(page.getContent());
    }
}
```

Also, note that the URL's should be REST-like. This means using the HTTP methods as the verbs and to have nouns in the URL. When naming API URLs, it's recommended to use nouns instead of verbs or adjectives. This is because the names represent the contents of a resource or the resources themselves. Rather than having a URL such as the following:

```
/locations/    # to get an overview of the locations
/locations/*id*/    # to view the details of one location
/locations/*id*/edit    # to edit the details of one location
/locations/*id*/device/*deviceid*/    # to view details of a device
/locations/*id*/device/*deviceid*/edit    # to view details of a device
/services/     # list of all the services
/services/*id/    # view details of a service
```

These should be mapped to URL's like this:

```
/locations/                            -> POST /locations
/locations/*id*/                       -> GET /locations/{id}
/locations/*id*/edit                   -> PUT /locations/{id}
/locations/*id*/device/*deviceid*/     -> GET /locations/{id}/device/{deviceid}
/locations/*id*/device/*deviceid*/edit -> PUT /locations/{id}/device/{deviceid}
/services/                             -> GET /services
/services/*id/                         -> GET /services/{id}
```

Here are some best practices for naming REST API endpoints:

- Use nouns to represent resources
- Avoid verbs or verb-noun combinations
- Use the same name for the same concept

HTTP verbs, or methods, tell the server what to do with the data identified by the URL. The most commonly used HTTP verbs are: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
These verbs correspond to the following operations: Create, Read, Update, Update Delete.